# comparing two lists of string and if one of the item match do some processing

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, foreach, compare, string-comparison

I have two lists of string. I want to compare each elements in one list with another and if at least one of them match then do some processing else dont do anything.

I dont know how to do. I do have the following lists and the code I used was SequenceEqual but my lead said its wrong as it just compares if its equal or not and does nothing. I couldn't disagree and I want to achieve my intended functionality I mentioned above. Please help. As you seem, order doesn't matter, here 123 is in both list but in different order, so it matches and hence do some processing as per my requirement.

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string> () { "123", "234" };

List<string> list2 = new List<string> () { "333", "234" , "123"};
```

Comment: You could use List.Intersect. If the resulting list is empty then no match

Comment: `list1.Any(x=> list2.Any(y=>x==y))`

Comment: @Steve: I actually have both list as string array and I convert to list :p lol. I dont know but for fantasy lol. Idont know how to compare...my lead advised me to use index of compare method using array, I dont know how to do it *Feels angel*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any Intersection in Two Collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627419/any-intersection-in-two-collections)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Intersect` to find common elements:

```
var intersecting = list1.Intersect(list2);
```

If you just want to know if there are common elements append `.Any()`:

```
bool atLeastOneCommonElement = intersecting.Any();
```

If you want to process them:

```
foreach(var commonElement in intersecting)
{
    // do something ...
}
```

Comment: I just want to set a status if there are at least one matching in those two list. This doesn’t throw bull exceptions if one list is empty? Also does it depend on order of items or not?

Comment: No exception and order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `Any` method for this :

```
var matchfound = list1.Any(x=> list2.Contains(x));
```

Now you can do conditional block on the `matchFound` if it returns `true` you can process what ever is required.

if you want to do case insentitive comparison then you will need to use `String.Equals` and can specify if case does not matter for comaparing those.

Comment: ok sure thank you. What if one list is empty? Will it throw exception?

Comment: What did you say sorry?

Comment: If one of the list is null then it might throw exception

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Your answer was quite easy and useful. In the moments of thinking about exception, I accepted another answer here where he says no exceptions on empty. But I just realised your code can achieve the same if I do null check first. But yours is more readable code thank you so much. I gave upvote

Answer (score 1):

You could check with Intersect and Any

```
var matchFound = list1.Intersect(list2).Any();
```

For example,

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>{ "123", "234" };
List<string> list2 = new List<string>{ "333", "234" , "123"};
var result = list1.Intersect(list2).Any();
```

Output `True`

```
List<string> list3 = new List<string>{"5656","8989"};
result = list1.Intersect(list3).Any();
```

Output `False`

Answer (score 1):

You need to take all those item that are matches from both list and then do code if match found like

```
foreach (var item in list1.Where(x => list2.Contains(x)))
{
    //do some processing here        
    Console.WriteLine($"Match found: {item}");        
}
```

In above code `foreach` iterate when `item` present in both list.

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ to find the matches; and then check the resulting array size as follows:

```
var intersect = list1.Where(el1=>list2.Any(el2=>el2==el1));
var isMatch = intersect.Count > 0;
```